# Install JS Node in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: node.js, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run Javascript in Jupyter Notebook (unless there is an equivalent notebook in JS where I can test my scripts easily) and for instance I want to run the following:

```
import pixiedust_node
%%node
var date = new Date();
print(date);
```

In order to install everything I tried:

`pip install pixiedust` , `pip install pixiedust_node` , `conda install -c akode pixiedust` , `jupyter pixiedust install`

and still, when I am trying to load the code in Jupyter, I am getting this:

[image]

and after trying this: `conda install -c anaconda nodejs`
or even this: `conda install -c conda-forge nodejs`

Comment: Always start here. https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels With most things you have multiple options that you have to choose between. But, that's better than no options.

Answer (score 5):

you can actually try to use https://github.com/n-riesco/ijavascript as the kernel for the notebook instead of using node over python

Comment: I have installed python2 and python3 kernel and JS worked. I can't run Python3 in jupyter though. I don't see any kernel option for Node.js either